# Gauss- Markov Efficiency?

Tags: regression, self-study, econometrics, heteroscedasticity

if I have a ragression model $y_i = x_i\beta + u_i$ were I know that the square of error have this $u^{2}=\gamma w^2_{i}+\epsilon_{1}$, where I know only that $E(\epsilon_{i}|w_{i})=0$,  $E(u_{i}|w_{i})=0$.

I can assume that the expected value of $x|u$ is equal to zero for the law of iterated expectation? and what about the homoskedasticity? If $E(u|w)=0$ also $E(u^{2}|w^{2})$ is equal to zero?

so an OLS estimator for $\beta$ is Gauss Markov efficiency?

Comment: what's $w_i$ and $\varepsilon_1$? random variables?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: And how can I estimate gamma?

Comment: Where did you get this model? Something is amiss here

Comment: I've it from my Advance Econometrics homework

Comment: you need to mark it with self-study tag then. there's a protocol on helping home works

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't know it.